# Showing $E[X] \geq P(X\geq 2)$ for a random variable under certain conditions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

> Let $X$ be a random variable with finite expectation, and suppose that $E[e^{-X}] \leq 1$. Prove that $E[X] \geq P(X\geq 2)$.

My first thought was to use Markov's inequality, but I can only use that if $X$ is non-negative, and in any case, the resulting inequality doesn't seem very helpful. Even if I assume that $X\geq -c$ and apply it to $Y = X+c$, I'm left to show $P(X\geq 2) \geq \frac{c}{c+1}$, which doesn't seem like it's always true.

I'm primarily unsure of how to use the $E[e^{-X}]$ condition; Jensen's inequality tells me that the expectation  is non-negative but there's presumably more to it.

Additionally, I tried rewriting the inequalities in terms of integrals and playing around with parts, but that didn't seem to lead anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how the hypothesis about the expectation comes into play, but here's my solution. I'll simply use the Markov inequality for a non-negative r.v. and $a > 0$ in the form

$$ E[X] \ge aP(X \ge a) $$

with $a = 2$. Remembering that probabilities are non-negative and using Markov we have:

$$ E[X] \ge P(X \ge 2) + P(X \ge 2) \ge P(X \ge 2) $$

--- Edit after the comments about non-negativity:

I think I saw the light :D I use the extended form of Markov inequality for monotonically increasing function:

**Theorem**

Let $\varphi$ be a monotonically increasing function for $x > 0$ and let X be a r.v., $a>0, \varphi(a) > 0$. Then

$$ P(X \ge a) \le \frac{\mathbb{E}[\varphi(X)]}{\varphi(a)}$$

In our case I'll consider the (somehwat artificial) function $\varphi(x):= x + e^{-x}-1$, which we can prove satisfy all the hypothesis with $a = 2$. Hence, since $1/\varphi(a) \le 1$ and using the bound for $e^{-X}$, we have

$$ \begin{align*} P(X \ge a) &\le \frac{\mathbb{E}[X+e^{-X}-1]}{\varphi(a)}  \\ &\le \mathbb{E}[X] + \mathbb{E}[e^{-X}] -1 \\ &\le \mathbb{E}[X] \end{align*}$$

Comment: How do u know $X$ is non-negative?

Comment: The OP said he can only use that X is non-negative. Perhaps I misinterpreted?

Comment: I think OP was saying they can only use Markov’s when $X$ is non-negative, not that that’s an assumption.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll think more then.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen the extended form. I guess this shows that $2$ isn't tight in the equality.

Comment: I think you still need to show that $\mathbb{E}[X+e^{-X}-1]\ge0$ (or at least consider the case when it's negative if it does happen). Otherwise, the step where you drop $\phi(a)$ doesn't hold.

Comment: we can notice that the argument is nonnegative and so is the expectation.

Comment: Slick argument. Really nice form of Markov which doesn't require nonnegativity of $X$.

Comment: I saw it [from below "**Theorem**"] this way: $P[x >2]\le P[\varphi(x)\ge \varphi(2)]$, and then since $\varphi(X)$ is a non-negative rv [even if $X$ is not nonnegative everywhere], one can use straight ol' Markov to bound $P[\varphi(x)\ge \varphi(2)]$.

Comment: The argument isn’t necessarily nonnegative though. $X+e^X-1$ could be less than $0$. Although I don’t think the expectation can be, I don’t think it’s an entirely trivial proof.

Comment: @VarunVejalla You missed a minus sign at the exponent.

Comment: @finch That’s extremely embarrassing haha, but explains my error!